# yum install throwing error 403 when trying to install from rhel-x86_64-server-6

Tags: linux, redhat, yum, package-management

To preface this, I don't have much Red Hat experience. Most of my experience is with Ubuntu. The server I'm working on right now is running Red Hat Enterprise 6.5.

I'm trying to do a simple `yum install ncurses-devel`, but I'm having some issues with 403 errors. I also get the same if I try to install gdal. The problem seems to be with the rhel-x86_64-server-6 in particular, but I can't figure out why.

```
$ sudo -E yum install ncurses ncurses-devel
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, rhnplugin, security, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
Setting up Install Process
Package ncurses-5.7-3.20090208.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package ncurses-devel.x86_64 0:5.7-3.20090208.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

===============================================================================================================================
 Package                      Arch                      Version                   Repository                   Size
===============================================================================================================================
Installing:
 ncurses-devel                x86_64                5.7-3.20090208.el6            rhel-x86_64-server-6         642 k

Transaction Summary
===============================================================================================================================
Install       1 Package(s)

Total download size: 642 k
Installed size: 0  
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:


Error Downloading Packages:
  ncurses-devel-5.7-3.20090208.el6.x86_64: failed to retrieve getPackage/ncurses-devel-5.7-3.20090208.el6.x86_64.rpm from rhel-x86_64-server-6
error was [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 403"
```

How do I fix this? Does it have something to do with `subscription-manager`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by changing

`sudo -E yum install ncurses ncurses-devel`

to

`sudo yum install ncurses ncurses-devel`

I was running into something earlier where `sudo yum` wasn't able to access the outside world (because of my work proxy), but apparently that was the cause of this issue.